# Non-existent child page URLs redirects to the image attachment URL instead of throwing 404

Tags: images, slug

Entering a child page that does not exist will redirect to the image attachment page, specifically, the image attachment with the same slug.

Say, entering `example.com/cars/volvo-car/` will redirect to the image attachment page with the URL `example.com/volvo-car/`.

The `volvo-car` image attachment's permalink reflects the image name on initial upload, but even after I changed the attachment's slug to something different like `volvo-car-image` the non-existent child page still redirects to it instead of firing the 404 error page.

I can't find any entries in the database that would cause the redirect. I also tried it with different websites on different servers, but still getting the same behavior.

How can I fix it or stop WordPress from doing it?

---

Another thing I have discovered is that the parent page doesn't have to exist before this happens. As long as you add the image attachment URL's slug after the parent slug, it would still redirect to the attachment page like `example.com/fasdfwefa/image-slug`.

Comment: Firstly have you cleared your cache?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to disable all attachment pages and redirect them to 404 page. Place this code in functions.php and try it again.

```
 add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_media_to_404' );
 function redirect_media_to_404() {
    if ( is_attachment() ) {
       global $wp_query;
       $wp_query->set_404();
       status_header( 404 );
       get_template_part( 404 ); 
       exit();
    }
 }
```